# Storing variables on app close in c#

Tags: c#, variables, save

I'm trying to save a few lists of strings so that if I close the program, I don't lose all the information.

I have these variables:

```
list<string> StudentName = new list<string>;
list<string> Email = new list<string>;
list<string> StudentID = new list<string>;
```

I add a new variable to each list after the user submits a form that is completely filled out. If someone were to close the application, I want to have all the variables in each list be saved. I have used the application settings to store data in the past but I don't know how many people will be using this app.

Comment: Depends on how you want to store this. You could go for  database with all the info since you are using lists

Comment: You could use a database to store this, or store your lists in xml file(s).

Comment: The downvote wasn't necessary. It's a legitimate question.

Comment: Perhaps you mean `List` instead of `list` and `new List<string>()` instead of `new list<string>`.

Comment: @DerreckDean, it's broad question (`Settings`, serializers, custom format of saving something into file, using other means of storing things: `Registry`, databases, etc., you can get 100 valid answers) with dozens of duplicates. The fact OP don't know word `serialization` doesn't makes question better. If his concern is "many people", than it is again broad: which technology (desktop, web), how many is "many people", etc. The most suitable answer really *depends*.

Comment: @Sinatr then why not use this post to list different methods? The point of SO is to answer questions, and even if this is a n00b question it could turn into basically different methods of storing data. You are right, there are 100+ different ways, but this could be a good list of methods to use as a starting point, listing the pros and cons of each method.

Comment: @DerreckDean, *if your question could be answered by an entire book, or has many valid answers, it's probably too broad for our format* (see [too broad](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)).

Answer (score 2):

One possiblity would be to aggregate the lists in a type

```
public class AppState
{
    public List<string> StudentName = new List<string>();
    public List<string> Email = new List<string>();
    public List<string> StudentID = new List<string>();
}
```

and use [Xml serialization and deserialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to store the data in a file.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the values in the database:

```
// I'd create a model to start with

public class Student
{
    public int StudentID {get; set;}
    public string StudentName {get; set;}
    public string Email {get; set;}
}

// Followed by a Controller to store the data:

public class StoreStudentOnAppClose()
{
    public void StoreStudents()
    {
       List<Student> studentList = new List<Student>();
       // Predefined method which you'll add to your class to grab each student from the database table.
       studentList = GetStudentList();
       foreach(var student in studentList)
        {
            var db = UmbracoContext.Application.DatabaseContext.Database;
            var insert = new Sql("INSERT INTO students VALUES('" + StudentID + "', '" + StudentName +"'. '" + Email +"' )");
            int res = db.Execute(insert);
        }
    }
}
```

This is obviously in the context of an Umbraco application however the point is the same, you'd just change your connection string.

Comment: Please don't recommend string concatenation, it is prone to SQL injection.

Comment: to avoid SQL injection you can always look here for more in-depth information regarding SQL Injection safe queries: [MSDN Protect from SQL Injection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx)